# Synchronized Output With Bash's Process Substitution

Tags: bash, process, synchronization, substitution

I have to multiply call an inflexible external tool that takes as arguments some input data and an output file to which it will write the processed data, for example:

```
some_prog() {  echo "modified_$1" > "$2"; }
```

For varying input, I want to call some_prog, filter the output and write the output of all calls into the same file "out_file". Additionally, I want to add a header line to the output file before each call of some_prog. Given the following dummy filter:

```
slow_filter() { 
    read input; sleep "0.000$(($RANDOM % 10))"; echo "filtered_$input"
}
```

I wrote the following code:

```
rm -f out_file
for input in test_input{1..8}; do
    echo "#Header_for_$input"  >> "out_file"
    some_prog $input >( slow_filter  >> "out_file" )
done
```

However, this will produce an out_file like this:

```
#Header_for_test_input1
#Header_for_test_input2
#Header_for_test_input3
#Header_for_test_input4
#Header_for_test_input5
#Header_for_test_input6
#Header_for_test_input7
#Header_for_test_input8
filtered_modified_test_input4
filtered_modified_test_input1
filtered_modified_test_input2
filtered_modified_test_input5
filtered_modified_test_input6
filtered_modified_test_input3
filtered_modified_test_input8
filtered_modified_test_input7
```

The output I expected was:

```
#Header_for_test_input1
filtered_modified_test_input1
#Header_for_test_input2
filtered_modified_test_input2
#Header_for_test_input3
filtered_modified_test_input3
#Header_for_test_input4
filtered_modified_test_input4
#Header_for_test_input5
filtered_modified_test_input5
#Header_for_test_input6
filtered_modified_test_input6
#Header_for_test_input7
filtered_modified_test_input7
#Header_for_test_input8
filtered_modified_test_input8
```

I realized that the >( ) process substitution forks the shell. Is there a way to synchronize the output of the subshells? Or is there another elegant solution to this problem? I want to avoid the obvious approach of writing to different files in each iteration because, in my code, the for loop has a few 100,000 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Write the header *inside* the process substitution, specifically in a command group with the filter so that the concatenated output is written to `out_file` as one stream.

```
rm -f out_file
for input in test_input{1..8}; do
    some_prog "$input" >( { echo "#Header_for_$input"; slow_filter; }  >> "out_file" )
done
```

---

As process substitution is truly asynchronous and there doesn't appear to be a way to wait for it to complete before executing the next iteration of the loop, I would use an explicit named pipe.

```
rm -f out_file pipe
mkfifo pipe
for input in test_input{1..8}; do
    some_prog "$input" pipe &
    echo "#Header_for_$input" >> out_file
    slow_filter < pipe >> out_file
done
```

(If `some_prog` doesn't work with a named pipe for some reason, you can use a regular file. In that case, you shouldn't run the command in the background.)

Comment: Can you share some light on how the `()` works here?

Comment: `some_prog` expects the name of a file to write to. The process substitution supplies a file name, but instead of the data being written directly to that file, it is passed as the standard input of the command inside the parentheses. The above is a shortcut for `some_prog "$input" output; echo "..." >> out_file; slow_filter < output >> out_file`, without the need to explicitly manage `output`. `output` is also typically a named pipe, not a regular disk file.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work for me (does it for you?). The headers still print before the output. The reason, I assume, is that echo writes the header to the file immediately, then slow_filter is called, and while it is still running the next iteration already starts and another echo prints the header before the slow_filter from the last iteration has the chance to finish.

Comment: You're right. I was expecting that the process substitution had to complete before `some_prog` could, but it really is asynchronous. Further, it does not appear that you can `wait` on it. I think you'll have to use an explicit temporary file (or at least, a temporary named pipe).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. As I noted in my post, the `for` loop is going to have >100,000 iterations. Since the behavior of `some_prog`, unfortunately, is to overwrite the output file, it seems to me that I had to create that many temporary files. Is there some way to avoid that?

Comment: The pipe, at least, is only created once. When `some_prog` writes to it, it blocks until `slow_filter` starts to read from it; `slow_filter` will read from the pipe until the writer closes the pipe, which will happen when `some_prog` finally completes. Essentially, this is how process substitution works; you just have to manage the details manually.

Comment: I wouldn't worry much about the number of temporary files that could be created, though. If the output is large, then the overhead of creating each file is negligible. If the output is small, it's possible all the IO will happen in the disk cache without ever having to commit any of the data to disk.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting approach (the named pipe). Though it does seem to work properly, for some reason the usage of the named pipe slowed down my script by a factor 10. I think I'll simply use a temporary file (see below), which seems to have much less overhead. Also, I'm not exactly sure under which circumstances the "< pipe" redirection blocks, waiting for ">pipe &" to finish. How does it know whether there is still data to be written to the pipe from a subprocess?

Comment: Reading from the pipe will block until more data is written, or until the writer closes its end.

Answer (score 1):

Since chepner's approach using a named pipe seems to be very slow in my "real world script" (about 10 times slower than this solution), the easiest and safest way to achieve what I want seems to be a temporary file:

```
rm -f out_file
tmp_file="$(mktemp --tmpdir my_temp_XXXXX.tmp)"
for input in test_input{1..8}; do
    some_prog "$input" "$tmp_file"
    {
        echo "#Header_for_$input"
        slow_filter < "$tmp_file"
    } >> out_file
done
rm "$tmp_file"
```

This way, the temporary file `tmp_file` gets overwritten in each iteration such that it can be kept in memory if the system's temp directory is a RAM disk.